# How to create a recovery disc for my Netbook running Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I heard there are many software or ways to do this. However, searching for any answers to this on the internet only returns results that tell you how to slip stream windows xp sp3 with xp. http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2325400,00.asp

Windows XP has a built in option to create recovery discs but it requires a floppy disc drive; which I cannot get for my Netbook. (I can try and get a DVD disc drive, if required)
http://createrecoverydisk.com/create-windows-xp-recovery-disk/

So my question still stands. Is it possible, and if yes how can I create a recovery discs for all my current software/drivers/programs in my netbook running windows XP.

Comment: What make and model Netbook is it?

Comment: The fact that it is a Netbook is mostly irrelevant (and I shouldn't have included it in my description of my issue). But for the record, it is a HP Mini 110-3105tu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use any decent disk imaging software to create a recovery disk - I personally use [macrium reflect free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp) or acronis or you could use a FOSS solution for an offline image such as [redo backup](http://redobackup.org/) or [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)

image the whole disk, and if anything happens, you can restore it to the same state. A proper recovery disk is much more complicated, and uses a basic install of windows, and unattended installs for the final bits of setup, but for your purposes this will do.

Comment: Macrium reflect free looks good. I haven't yet used it but shall give it a try. Thanks for your answer. And sorry I can't vote, I need a reputation of 15 to do that.

Comment: fill up your user profile - it'll give you 100 rep ;p

Comment: Filled. It gave me an autobiographer badge. Good enough :).

Comment: Just so you know, filling up the user profile does not give you 100 rep. Merging your stack exchange accounts with at least one account that has 200 rep gives the new account 100 rep. Thought you might like to know.

Comment: Its been a year, i kind of forgot ;p